# Issues with Spacy in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

Im trying my hands at spacy but it seems the documentation is flawed. Just to get started with it took me quite long. The very first issue I faced was :-

```
import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load("en")

Warning: no model found for 'en'
Only loading the 'en' tokenizer.
```

Which I solved by importing the module

```
import en_core_web_sm as en_core
nlp=en_core.load()
```

But now when Im trying to run this code

```
from numpy import dot 
from numpy.linalg import norm 
from spacy.en import English
parser = English()

#Generate word vector of the word - apple  
apple = parser.vocab[u'apple']

#Cosine similarity function 
cosine = lambda v1, v2: dot(v1, v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2))
others = list({w for w in parser.vocab if w.has_vector and w.orth_.islower() and w.lower_ != unicode("apple")})

# sort by similarity score
others.sort(key=lambda w: cosine(w.vector, apple.vector)) 
others.reverse()


print "top most similar words to apple:" 
for word in others[:10]:
    print word.orth_
```

Im getting

```
>>top most similar words to apple:
```

Whereas I should be getting

```
>> top most similar words to apple: 
>> apples iphone fruit juice cherry lemon banana pie mac orange
```

Comment: This works fine for me .

Answer (score 2):

Running python -m spacy.en.download all as an Adminstrator fixed the problem.